# Cronjob or rake task for automate a download, unzip and move to a specified directory

Tags: cron, rake-task

I'm not sure if this should be achieved using cron job or rake task.

There is this large zipped file (250MB+) that is provided by third-party, that is updated weekly. I can't be downloading it to my local machine and uploading to the server weekly to replace the old data. Is there anyway I can write such workflow:

1. Download a zipped file from this URL: `http://download.abc.com/data.zip` every Sunday 4am.
2. Unzip it to `data`.
3. Move the folder, its subfolders and contents to `public/data` and replace old `public/data`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bash script. Install it with `crontab -e`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
mkdir data
cd data
wget http://download.abc.com/data.zip
unzip data.zip
rm -rf /public/data/*
mv data/* /public/data/
chown -R www-data:www-data /public/data/
```

Didn't test it, but it should do that, what you want.
Don't forget to adapt owner/group `www-data:www-data` to your own needs.